# Using loops inside Openrowset

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, t-sql, openrowset

I'm trying to execute a query across around 200 servers using openrowset function.
This function needs to execute in a loop - the query is sucessfull in SQL Server 2012 environments, but failing in older ones.
I'll illustrate this issue with a simple query:

```
    SELECT CAST(a.ServerName AS varchar(50)), CAST(a.LoginName AS varchar(50)) 
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=2012ServerName;Trusted_Connection=yes;','
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @LoginName sysname
DECLARE @FinalResults TABLE (LoginName varchar(50))
DECLARE LoginsCursor CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT sl.Name LoginName
FROM master.dbo.syslogins sl WITH (NOLOCK)
OPEN LoginsCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM LoginsCursor INTO @LoginName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN
INSERT INTO @FinalResults
SELECT @LoginName
FETCH NEXT FROM LoginsCursor INTO @LoginName
END 
CLOSE LoginsCursor
DEALLOCATE LoginsCursor
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(''ServerName'') ServerName , LoginName FROM @FinalResults
') AS a
```

Result is success, but if I'll change provider to SQLNCLI10(I'm running this query from SQL Server 2012) 
It will fail. Also if I'll change server name to server with previous SQL version this query will fail.
Is there an update in native client 11 that makes this query sucessful and is there a way to overcome this problem?

Comment: What error messages do you get when the SQLNCLI10 fails?

Comment: Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot process the object "Query text
". The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "(null)" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object

Comment: This is a simple logicless query that anyone can run on his mashine to check this issue, just replace 2012ServerName with real server name

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious, but you're certain you have rights to access the failing server(s)?

Comment: :-) Yes, no problem with that.
I can even fail the query that I wrote, simply by changing SQLNCLI to SQLNCLI10

Comment: Is there a reason you are changing the provider name to SQLNCLI10 vs SQLNCLI?  When you create a linked server and use SQLNCLI it tells the engine to use the most current native client installed.  My guess is by dictating which client to use across all 200 servers, you are failing because there are different versions.  You can use system sp "sp_linkedservers" to see the provider name of the linked servers.  Assuming all your linked servers are were set up as Native Client SQL servers you shouldn't need to change it.